# Coding a simple class

Tags: c++

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around the concept of coding a class. In this example I'm trying to create a simple class that adds and subtracts numbers.

```
// Class

class CalculateNumbers {
     private:
       int numberOne;
       int numberTwo;

     public:

       AddNumbers();
       SubtractNumbers();         
 }

 CalculateNumbers::AddNumbers(int a, int b) { 
        //  ???        
 }


 CalculateNumbers::SubtractNumbers(int a, int b) { 

 } 

CalculateNumbers calcInstance;

calcInstance.AddNumbers();
```

Comment: So what is your question?...

Comment: Do you really need a class for this?

Comment: Yes, the reason I am coding a basic class like this is to understand how classes work..

Comment: @AlanCA You need to learn how to write functions first, before classes.

Comment: You also need to include a question in your question, because without a question one cannot write an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you read up on basic C++ syntax before digging too deep into classes. You have some fundamental problems with not just the functions you've written but, also in how you use them.

**Functions need to have a return type**

Both your add and subtract functions do not have a return type; if you want a function that returns nothing, you specify the return type as `void`

**When calling a function with parameters, pass them some**

When you call AddNumbers, you aren't passing it any numbers to add. What are you trying to do there? My guess is you're looking for something more like this:

```
class CalculateNumbers
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        // Pass the two numbers you want calculations to be done on
        CalculateNumbers(int a, int b); 

        int AddNumbers();
        int SubtractNumbers();

    private:
        int m_firstNumber;
        int m_secondNumber;
};


CalculateNumbers::CalculateNumbers(int a, int b)
    : m_firstNumber(a)
    , m_secondNumber(b)
{

}

int CalculateNumbers::AddNumbers()
{
    return m_firstNumber + m_secondNumber;
}

int CalculateNumbers::SubtractNumbers()
{
    return m_firstNumber - m_secondNumber;
}


CalculateNumbers instance(10, 5);

instance.AddNumbers(); // returns 15
instance.SubtractNumbers(); // returns 5
```

In the future it would be helpful if you included more details about what you're attempting to accomplish, and even better is if you have a specific question you'd like answered.

Comment: Thanks, this helps greatly. Why did you include the part with the : and ,?

Comment: That's whats called an initializer list. Its used for initializing the member variables as part of construction. Its similar to initalizing the values in the constructor body.